# How well can we hide an executable (apk/ipa) in an image

Tags: malware, mobile, steganography, social-media

Guys the basic idea behind this question is to gather your thoughts on the below scenario:

I was listening to a news program and one of the cyber security researchers, actually a very senior guy, was the guest. He was warning about executable embedded Gif/Png images circulating in Whatsapp. He explains that anyone who open those images will trigger execution of the hidden payload and could result in loss of personal information.

Is it possible by any means to create a similar image, which I can send via whatsapp or any messenger. Once the victim opens it in Android/Ios the payload has to execute on the background with zero interaction from victim and steal his data. My awareness about android/ios tells such a scenario is not possible. I need your thoughts on this.

Would appreciate some inputs based on the mobile platform.

Comment: Yes there are many discussions. I could not see any discussion which is specific to android/ios.

Comment: These answers apply to everything from Windows to iOS to Android to PS4 to those silly fad electronic screens that you hang on your wall to look at slideshows of your family intermixed with stock photos of flowers. If it can display images, it can have vulnerabilities in rendering.